# hashing different tuples in python give identical result

Tags: python, hash, tuples

I'm working with sets of integer matrices, and I thought representing them as tuples made sense, as they are hashable. However the hash() function gave me strange results for tuples:

```
hash(((1, -1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, -1)))

Out[147]: -697649482279922733

hash(((1, 0, -1), (1, 0, 0), (1, -1, 0)))

Out[148]: -697649482279922733
```

As you can see, these two different tuples have the same hash value. Note that they are actually pretty similar (exchange of the first and last subtuples), however I couldn't find a more minimal example: `((0,1),(0,0))` and `((0,0),(0,1))` have different hash values for example.

Any clue of what's going on? I  can't believe that it's just incredibly bad luck... Now that I have found where the problem is I could bypass it easily, but I thought it was worth mentioning here anyway.

Comment: So bad luck it is... Wow. Still, I find it weird that it's that easy to find a hash redundancy. This caused issues because of a lame piece of code - I used hash value to test equality, which I'll definitely never do again. Thanks!

Comment: Nearly 5 years on, I've had to drastically update my answer as someone managed to convince the Python core developers that there indeed was a problem with the Python tuple hashing method. :-) Hope you don't mind! However, you still should not use hashing to stand in for equality testing.. It can, at best, only be used to prove the opposite (two values that produce different hash values must be unequal, but the inverse is not always true).

Comment: Only seeing this now - thanks Martijn! Since then I've moved on to better coding practice, a bit thanks to you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Until Python 3.8, the hash of a tuple is based on the hashes of the content using the following formula (from the [`tuplehash()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.7/Objects/tupleobject.c#L347-L369)):

```c
Py_uhash_t mult = _PyHASH_MULTIPLIER; /* defined as 1000003UL == 0xf4243 */
x = 0x345678UL;
p = v->ob_item;
while (--len >= 0) {
    y = PyObject_Hash(*p++);
    if (y == -1)
        return -1;
    x = (x ^ y) * mult;
    /* the cast might truncate len; that doesn't change hash stability */
    mult += (Py_hash_t)(82520UL + len + len);
}
x += 97531UL;
if (x == (Py_uhash_t)-1)
    x = -2;
return x;
```

This is a method known as the [FNV-1 (Fowler / Noll / Vo) hash method](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/index.html#FNV-1a).

As it happens, that formula produces the exact same output for `(1, 0, -1)` and `(1, -1, 0)`:

```
>>> hash((1, -1, 0))
-2528505496374624146
>>> hash((1, 0, -1))
-2528505496374624146
```

because the hashes for the 3 contained integers are `1`, `0` and `-2`:

```
>>> hash(1)
1
>>> hash(0)
0
>>> hash(-1)
-2
```

and swapping the `0` and the `-2` has no actual influence on the outcome.

So the hashes for the 3 contained tuples don't change between the two examples, so the final hash doesn't change either.

This is just a coincidence, and I'd expect that in practice this doesn't happen all *that* often and dictionaries and sets already can handle collisions just fine.

However, a few years after writing my original answer, it turns out that my expectation was misplaced! The above `tuplehash()` implementation was in place for 14 years, until [someone insisted that there *was* a problem with the scheme](https://bugs.python.org/issue34751). It turns out that certain value *combinations* (such as `4` and `-4`, or `0.25` and `0.5`) drastically reduced the possible hash values the method could output:

```
>>> import sys; from itertools import product
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> values = (0.25, 0.5)
>>> sum(1 for _ in product(values, repeat=20))  # 20 elements in each tuple
1048576
>>> len(set(map(hash, product(values, repeat=20))))
32
```

The above creates all 1048576 (2 ** 20 == 1024 ** 2) possible 20-value tuples that combine `0.25` and `0.5`. Ideally, they all should have a different hash value, or at least have a very large number of different hash values. But the above `tuplehash()` function only produced 32 unique values. Each of those 32 unique hashes applies to 32768 (2 ** 15) such combinations:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(Counter(map(hash, product(values, repeat=20))).values())
Counter({32768: 32})
```

This is actually quite a *big* problem! The above issue also comes into play for `1, -1, 0`, it just isn't as pronounced; testing here with 3 ** 12 == 531441 combinations:

```
>>> values = (1, -1, 0)
>>> sum(1 for _ in product(values, repeat=12))
531441
>>> len(set(map(hash, product(values, repeat=12))))
238605
>>> Counter(Counter(map(hash, product(values, repeat=12))).values())
Counter({1: 153005, 2: 51006, 4: 21730, 8: 8424, 16: 3012, 32: 994, 64: 314, 128: 92, 256: 20, 512: 6, 1024: 2})
```

so 153005 of the hashes produced for those 12-element tuples are all using a single hash.

So in Python 3.8, the [implementation was switched](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/aeb1be5868623c9cd9cf6d7de3015a43fb005815) from FNV-1a to an adaptation of the [xxHash fast digest scheme](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/master/doc/xxhash_spec.md). See the [new `tuplehash()` function implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7b3ab5921fa25ed8b97b6296f97c5c78aacf5447/Objects/tupleobject.c#L338-L391) for details.

This new method performs great on the examples from your question:

```
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> hash((1, -1, 0))
426056430309831993
>>> hash((1, 0, -1))
-7823806182320511195
>>> hash(((1, -1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, -1)))
-6252168277346219339
>>> hash(((1, 0, -1), (1, 0, 0), (1, -1, 0)))
-5221381175350594014
```

as well as the pathological cases I discussed above:

```
>>> values = (0.25, 0.5)
>>> len(set(map(hash, product(values, repeat=20))))
1048576
>>> values = (1, -1, 0)
>>> len(set(map(hash, product(values, repeat=12))))
531441
```

Comment: Note that Py3.8 introduces a different algorithm for hashing tuples: https://bugs.python.org/issue34751 (the arguments about hashes not having to be unique still hold!)

Comment: @TomaszGandor: Thanks again for that link. I had already seen that the implementation had changed but had forgotten about this answer. I've now expanded it to show that there indeed was a problem with the tuple hashing function before.

Answer (score 1):

Seems strange, but don't use `hash` either way: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash

> [hash is] used to quickly compare dictionary keys during a dictionary lookup.

It's not actually made for general purpose hashing - dictionaries have extra checks beyond simple hash equality. For general purpose hashing, use [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)